# Text overflowing in fixed div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQqc6.png)On my chat conversation page, the messages are overflowing in a fixed position, and messages are overflowing.

I need to display div elements one by one.The div elements are also displaying side by side. How can I correct that?

I think I did mistake in div position.

Any ideas or suggest some articles?

I have given a sample code below.

Thanks in Advance!

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<style type="text/css">
.mright{
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;

 }


 .mleft{
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;

 }

.pbcb{

position:fixed;
  background-color: #ECF0F1;
  left:0%;
  right:26%;
  top:10%;
  bottom:10%;

 overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:scroll;
 padding:3px;

    transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
.sub{
         transform:rotateX(180deg);

}
</style>
<body>
<div class="pbcb">
<div class="sub">

<div  style="float:right;background-color:yellow;clear:both;margin-bottom:10px;height:auto;">

   <button class="btn dropdown-toggle mright" style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black;">one</button>
              
 </div>
<div class="pbcb">
<div  style="float:right;background-color:yellow;clear:both;margin-bottom:10px;height:auto;">

   <button class="btn dropdown-toggle mright" style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black;">two</button>
              
 </div>
<div class="pbcb">
<div  style="float:right;background-color:yellow;clear:both;margin-bottom:10px;height:auto;">

   <button class="btn dropdown-toggle mright" style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black;">three</button>
              
 </div>
<div class="pbcb">
<div  style="float:right;background-color:yellow;clear:both;margin-bottom:10px;height:auto;">

   <button class="btn dropdown-toggle mright" style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black;">four</button>
              
 </div>
<div class="pbcb">
<div  style="float:right;background-color:yellow;clear:both;margin-bottom:10px;height:auto;">

   <button class="btn dropdown-toggle mright" style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black;">five</button>
              
 </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have design or wireframe just share it. That will be easy to understand what do you want actually...

Comment: @KararBarcha I added the screenshot can you please check. If I give more than one line of text it overflowing out of div.

Comment: Okay let me write code for you...

Answer (score 1):

> This is just sample code, You can make it more better...

```css
.main{
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
}
.top-bar{
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.msg-bar{
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 0px; 
  width: 100px;
  
}
.msg-bar .msg{
  background-color: #512acc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.msg-bar .msg:last-child{
margin-bottom: 90px;
}
.msg-bar .msg h4{ 
color: #fff;
}
.msg-bar .msg p{ 
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="top-bar"> </div>
 

<div class="msg-bar">
<div class="msg">
<h4>Msg #1 </h4>
<p> 12-12-2012 </p>
</div>
<div class="msg">
<h4>Msg #1 </h4>
<p> 12-12-2012 </p>
</div>
<div class="msg">
<h4>Msg #1 </h4>
<p> 12-12-2012 </p>
</div>
<div class="msg">
<h4>Msg #1 </h4>
<p> 12-12-2012 </p>
</div>
<div class="msg">
<h4>Msg #1 </h4>
<p> 12-12-2012 </p>
</div>
<div class="msg">
<h4>Msg #1 </h4>
<p> 12-12-2012 </p>
</div>
<div class="msg">
<h4>Msg #1 </h4>
<p> 12-12-2012 </p>
</div>
<div class="msg">
<h4>Msg #1 </h4>
<p> 12-12-2012 </p>
</div>
</div> 

</div>
```